# How to find relavant element from an array based on index using number in the loop?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, key, element

I've an array and I need to find out the key values based on index number using flag (another number).

```
array(
    [0] => 'apple',
    [1] => 'banana',
    [2] => 'orange',
    [3] => 'graps',
)
```

For example,

If the flag number is `1` then I need the output of 1st element `array([0]=>'apple')`.

If the flag number is `2` then I need the output of 2nd element `array([1] => 'banana')`.

If the flag number is `3` then the output should be `array([2] => 'orange')`.

If the flag number is `4` then the output should be `array([3] => 'graps')`.

If the flag number is `5` then the output should be `array([0] => 'apple')` based on loop and so on.

Comment: Okay, so, like for flag 10 you will get output as array([1] => 'banana') ?

Comment: Do you want the values only (i.e. "apple", "banana")? Or do you want an array with both the key and value of the item (i.e. `array(0 => 'apple')`, `array(1 => 'banana')`)?

Comment: `$array[($index - 1) % count($array)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use modulo (`%`) operator to make the flag get back to the first index:

```
function get_elem($arr, $index) {

  return $arr[($index - 1) % count($arr)];
}
```

Working example: https://repl.it/repls/AptDeliriousCad